# GeForce GT 730M stopped working on Ubuntu 16.04 after attempted drived update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am an absolute Linux and Ubuntu novice and I have run into a problem that leaves me dumbfounded:

I have a Lenovo Ideapad U430 sporting a GeForce GT 730M graphics card. Some time ago, after much tinkering, I got the Nvidia driver to work (one from the graphics-drivers repository). I could use Nvidia X Settings to switch between the Nvidia and the Intel adapter, all was well in the kingdom.

However, recently I had the crazy idea to upgrade my driver to the most recent version and things went downhill pretty quickly. I can install the driver but when I reboot, I get some (to me) cryptic message about

> bbswitch: no suitable _dsm call found

and Ubuntu starts with some sort of low graphics mode and a selection menu with several options, none of which works.

So all I can do by this point is go to the console, purge the nvidia driver and now I am stuck with nouveau and can only use my intel video adapter.

I have tried every solution to any remotely similar problem I could find here on this board, alas, to no avail.

Let me know what log files or whathaveyou you need from me, I am unfortunately utterly clueless about how to give all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through all the solutions to similar problems I could find, nothing helped.

So instead, I went and re-installed Ubuntu, keeping my /home directory. I then installed the Nvidia driver "versio 375.66 (proprietary, tested)" under "Additional Drivers" and now everything is working again.